# Persistent LiveUSB fails to install Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, live-usb

I have live Ubuntu (tried also Mint and Kubuntu, same effect) on a USB stick with persistence enabled. My laptop is however very noisy (VGA still on max?). I solved this problem before back with Mint 7 Gloria like:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (restart xserver). VGA then behaved reasonably.

I can not reproduce these steps anymore with latest Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Mint.

Can the problem be that I'm on a LiveUSB? Is it normal, then when selecting "Additional Drivers" for nVidia they always fail to install (those proprietary)?

Comment: Yes, you can not install system packages from live usb installation.

Comment: I tried f.e. NetBeans and they were installed successfully (persistence). So this is a difference?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can not install system packages from live usb installation. – João Pinto Jan 20 '11 at 21:31