# Ubuntu Live usb with persistence mode, how to install nvidia driver?

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, live-usb

Im trying to install graphics drivers on my usb ubuntu live, but i get errors when i activate them. through the hardware drive window.

would be nice if some gave me a tutorial of installing ubuntu 10.04 32bit on a usb drive for a live and persistence mode. then installing nvidia drivers.

i even tried manually installing it, but when i stop the x-server i get a screen saying checking battery and an [OK] at the far right. and it just sits there.

need help please!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persistent LiveUSB fails to install Nvidia drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22490/persistent-liveusb-fails-to-install-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Process: use at your own risk

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Select the nvidia driver from the X server driver list and follow the on-screen steps to complete the configuration

Once finished with the configuration, hold down Ctrl+Alt+Backspace to restart X server. You should be presented with a nice NVIDIA splash screen signaling that the driver is installed and working

You can test this in the terminal by typing glxinfo | grep direct (the output should be direct rendering: yes)

You can also type glxgears to watch your card at work

[source](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/installing-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-edgy/)