# I want to install Nvidia Drivers off a bootable USB. How?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, usb

So I am trying to have Ubuntu and the drivers on the same bootable USB drive. Like if I boot my USB on another desktop I would still be able to use that driver to use the GPU of the desktop. I saw another person with a similar question and am requesting a step-by-step guide or a video on how to do it. I would really appreciate it if someone make a video since I am dumb. If you can please make a **really** Step by step tutorial.
Please
Latest version of Ubuntu
Nvida Drivers latest for gtx 1660 super

Comment: You've provided few specific details; such as what product, release of Ubuntu, what type of install or *live* session you're asking about.  Assuming it's a Ubuntu Desktop and and installed system on thumb-drive it's just `apt install` & reboot.  That won't help *live* systems (nor Core systems) but you didn't give specifics.

Comment: added some more info, It is a live session and ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Latest version of Ubuntu isn't very specific; latest release?   latest LTS (ie. four releases ago), latest daily? latest server? latest desktop? latest core?   ie. specific details.  My prior comment fully applies for the *latest* Ubuntu with conditions still applying as per first comment (you've added it's *live*, do you have *persistence*? - why not just install to thumb-drive?)

Comment: If you need a step-by-step tutorial AND you want to install from a USB stick, then reconsider your approach. You are choosing a needlessly difficult method for a beginner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Live usb with persistence mode, how to install nvidia driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116507/ubuntu-live-usb-with-persistence-mode-how-to-install-nvidia-driver)

Answer (score 2):

If you have internet access on the machine, you don't need to install from a USB drive.  The recommended method is to use the Ubuntu "Software & Updates" GUI or the APT package manager as it will take care of installing everything for you as well as keeping everything up to date when you update your system.  Manually installing drivers will cause the drivers to break when you update your system in the future.

See the link below for instructions.  Use the GUI method if you have a graphical desktop or the command line interface (CLI) method if you want to use the terminal.  I would not recommend installing via PPA or manually from NVIDIA's website for the same reasons I listed above.
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-linux